# Aligning inputs in columns

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://evenimente.academiasuccesului.ro/?event=4

At the bottom you'll see a form "inregistreaza-te pentru acest eveniment"

I want to know how these forms can align in line as in the picture below.

http://i61.tinypic.com/k3xjqd.png

This is code for my form:

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input id="yourname" name="yourname" type="text" value="Nume" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Nume';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Nume') {this.value = '';}">

<input id="email" name="youremail" type="text" value="Adresa de Email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Adresa de Email';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Adresa de Email') {this.value = '';}"><input id="email" name="yourtelephone" type="text" value="Nr. de Tel." onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Nr. de Tel.';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Nr. de Tel.') {this.value = '';}"><input type="hidden" name="yourplaces" value="1"><input id="yourblank1" name="yourblank1" type="text" value="Cod Cupon" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Cod Cupon';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Cod Cupon') {this.value = '';}"><textarea rows="4" label="message" name="yourmessage" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Mesaj';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Mesaj') {this.value = '';}">Mesaj</textarea><input type="submit" value="Inregistreaza-te" id="submit" name="qemregister">

        </form>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple IDs on the same page. Thats wrong from both javascript and css point of view. If you can control your form, then it will be easier to add 3 wrappers to form your columns of 33.333333% each and float them.

Then, at some point, because your site is responsive, you need a bit of media queries at the end of you CSS file to align vertically all your elements.